# with 4.12.9 it seems the Flutter SDK is now supporting Android Auto and CarPlay. Any tips as I could not find the MapViewHost class

Tags: here-api

I tried to support Android Auto and CarPlay using the 4.12.9 Flutter SDK.
I did not understand or find an example on how to use the new classes
Any example or tip on how to do that?

Comment: MapViewHost.kt and MapViewHost.swift are part of the plugin package as native source files. The viewID seems to be the same that can be set to HereMapController.

Comment: Any tip on how I could use it?